# Zend_Navigation - set menu item to visible in controller?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

Zend_Navigation question

I want a menu item to only be visible if certain conditions apply. So initially in my nav.xml I have

```
   <item_one>...<visible>0</visible></item_one>
```

Is it possible to set `item_one` to visible in `controller->init()` if a condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->view->navigation()->findBy('property_name','value')->setVisible(true);
```